# Фигурные скобки в баше

Tags: bash, shell

есть одно выражение: `echo ${100}` В терминале оно возвращает пустое значение. В документации не нашел, почему так происходит?

Comment: [Клац](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${100}` — это значение параметра номер сто.

в терминале (или эмуляторе терминала) оболочка обычно запускается вообще без каких-либо параметров (только с какими-нибудь опциями), соответственно, значения всех параметров (начиная с первого — `$1` или `${1}`) будут пустыми.

это ни в коем случае не *bash*-специфично, а описано в стандарте *posix*:

- [positional parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_01)
- по поводу фигурных скобок там же сказано, что если номер больше девяти (т.е. состоит больше чем из одной цифры), то его нужно заключить в фигурные скобки, т.е., использовать т.н. [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).